# How can I Import/Export Dictionary Elements

Tags: c#, dictionary

So basically, I have a Dictionary that the user can add values to and can print all keys and their values.

I would like to know how I would go about exporting those keys and values to an external files and re-import them into the program so that I can use print all function to see everything that has been saved before. Basically a save function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Dictionary` has `Keys` and `Values` collections you can use `File.WriteAllLines()` method to write them to a file of your choosing

Comment: But would the keys and values remain 'together' if I do this?

Comment: ofcourse , here's an example as an _.CSV_ output style `File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", myDictionary.Select(s => String.Format("{0};{1}", s.Key, s.Value)));`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer JSON format for serialization because of its simplicity, you just need to install `Newtonsoft.Json` package. It may not have as good perfomance as other approaches, but this method is fine, if you have relatively small amount of data.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "test", "value" },
};

var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
File.WriteAllText("dict.json", jsonContent);

var fileContent = File.ReadAllText("dict.json");
var newDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(fileContent);
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll take a look at it. Cheers!